# how to produce and consume different avro entities on the same topic?

Tags: apache-kafka, avro, confluent-platform, confluent-schema-registry

there has been this article from Martin Kleppmann (on Confluent blog) saying its possible to have different event types into the same kafka topic:
[Should You Put Several Event Types in the Same Kafka Topic](https://www.confluent.io/blog/put-several-event-types-kafka-topic/)

Here is the related code change request:
[New (key|value).multi.type option for Avro serialization](https://github.com/confluentinc/schema-registry/pull/680)

The question i have is, how can this be done? How do i define configure a producer and consumer that can process different avro entities to one common topic?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: also how do i configure this in the schema registry? and how does it work with the serializing and deserializing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [added properties](https://docs.confluent.io/current/schema-registry/docs/serializer-formatter.html#subject-name-strategy) are

```
key.subject.name.strategy
value.subject.name.strategy
```

You would use `.configure` method of the `KafkaAvroSerializer` to take advantage of these.

I suggest [looking at the unit tests](https://github.com/confluentinc/schema-registry/pull/680/files#diff-2473544f599c99a5add5b9d963878f55R206) because it doesn't seem there is an in-depth documentation section on how to use it.

Comment: hi, thanks for giving me an answer, it helped a little to see a unit test. unfortunately, it looks like this solution (after viewing those unit tests) involves working with generic avro records, when i was hoping it would be available for specific avro records.

Comment: There is a separate config for using a SpecificRecord and a separate test for it. They should be able to be combined. https://github.com/confluentinc/schema-registry/blob/master/avro-serializer/src/test/java/io/confluent/kafka/serializers/KafkaAvroSerializerTest.java#L272